# Origine et sens de "prix militaire" pour exprimer "prix réduits"

Tags: expressions, usage, étymologie, histoire, militaire

Dans un magasin opticien j'ai lu sur un affiche :

> Prix militaire

pour promouvoir (je pense) des prix réduits.

D'où vient cette connotation de l'expression "prix militaire" ? Quelle est son origine ?

Comment: Peut-être une réduction accordée au(x) militaire(s) ?

Comment: @Toto Non ; j'ai posé la question à un opticien du magasin. Il m'a dit que ça (les prix réduits) concerne tout le monde et n'a pas une connection particulière avec les militaires.

Comment: Cette expression m'est inconnue, et je pense ne pas être le seul dans ce cas. -- off topic : "n'a pas de **rapport** ou de **lien** particulier" (ou *n'a pas de conne**x**ion particulière" si tu veux) --

Comment: @jlliagre Merci !

Comment: Jamais entendu cette expression non plus, certainement pas en tout cas sans aucun lien avec les militaires... Je ne sais pas d'où cet opticien a sorti cette expression mais je crains qu'il n'y aie pas grand monde qui la comprenne...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je connais, et ai utilisé à l'époque de la conscription obligatoire, le *tarif militaire*. Mais ça ne s'appliquait qu'à la SNCF pour désigner un tarif réduit de 75%. Certains l'appelaient aussi *quart de place*.

Hors ce contexte précis, je n'ai pas entendu parler d'expressions similaires.